# PHP Array Replace Issue

Tags: php

So recently I got stuck in some sort of array combine and replace situation.

I had this array:

```
array(5) {
  ["De"]=>
  string(7) "treatee"
  ["Para"]=>
  string(13) "Cristina Isabel Gnap"
  ["Principio"]=>
  string(36) "Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o."
  ["Descricao"]=>
  string(8) "sadsadsa"
}
```

I wanted to remove the middle name from `['Para']` field so I made a `for` loop like this:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
      $array = explode(' ', $rows[$i]['Para']);
      $firstName = $array[0];
      $lastName = $array[count($array) - 1];
      $combineNames= $primeiroNome." ".$ultimoNome;
      $namesCombined= str_split($combineNomes, 30);
      $result = array_replace($rows[$i], $nomesArray);
}
```

The result of course, display this:

```
array(5) {
 ["De"]=>
 string(7) "treatee"
 ["Para"]=>
 string(20) "Cristina Isabel Gnap"
 ["Principio"]=>
 string(36) "Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o."
 ["Descricao"]=>
 string(8) "sadsadsa"
 ["0"]=>
 string(13) "Cristina Gnap"
}
```

But what I actually **need** to do, is to replace the `["Para"]` field with the new `["0"]` field, but it seems when I put in the `for` something like `$result = array_replace($rows[$i]['Para'], $nomesArray);` it returns this:

`Warning: array_replace(): Argument #1 is not an array`

Can anyone help me? =D

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over an array you can use a foreach loop. `$row` is prefixed with an `&` so that any changes you make will be applied to the original array (passing by reference).

```
foreach ($rows as &$row) {

  $original_string = $row['Para'];  

  // make your changes here and assign the new value to $new_string

  $row['Para'] = $new_string;
}
```

For reference,
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of preg_split and foreach loop to achieve as shown below. By the way, you can test the result [here:](https://eval.in/586191)

```
    <?php
        $arr = [
        "De"        =>"treatee",
        "Para"      => "Cristina Isabel Gnap",
        "Principio" =>"Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o.",
        "Descricao" =>"sadsadsa",
        ];

        var_dump($arr);


        foreach($arr as $key=>&$value){
            if($key == "Para"){
                if(is_string($value)) {
                    $arrSplits = preg_split("#\s#", $value);
                    if (count($arrSplits) == 3) {
                        unset($arrSplits[1]);
                        $arr[$key] = implode(" ", $arrSplits);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($arr);
```

**RESULT OF 1ST VAR_DUMP**

```
        array (size=4)
          'De' => string 'treatee' (length=7)
          'Para' => string 'Cristina Isabel Gnap' (length=20)
          'Principio' => string 'Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o.' (length=42)
          'Descricao' => string 'sadsadsa' (length=8)
```

**RESULT OF 2ND VAR_DUMP**

```
        array (size=4)
          'De' => string 'treatee' (length=7)
          'Para' => string 'Cristina Gnap' (length=13)
          'Principio' => string 'Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o.' (length=42)
          'Descricao' => string 'sadsadsa' (length=8)
```

Alternatively, You could encapsulate the above into a Function that accepts an Array and pass-in your array like so:

```
    <?php 
        function removeMiddleNamesFromArray(&$dataArray){
            foreach($dataArray as $key=>&$value){
                if($key == "Para"){
                    if(is_string($value)){
                        $arrSplits      = preg_split("#\s#", $value);
                        if( count($arrSplits) == 3){
                            unset($arrSplits[1]);
                            $arr[$key]  = implode(" ", $arrSplits);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $dataArray;
        }

        var_dump(removeMiddleNamesFromArray($arr));
```

**DUMPS**

```
        array (size=4)
          'De' => string 'treatee' (length=7)
          'Para' => string 'Cristina Gnap' (length=13)
          'Principio' => string 'Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o.' (length=42)
          'Descricao' => string 'sadsadsa' (length=8)
```

Alternatively, You could encapsulate the above into a Function that accepts an Array and pass-in your array like so:

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although, it returns me this: `Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: @FelipeBueno  In that case the Original Array contains some other arrays... The post has now been updated to take that into consideration....

Answer (score 0):

Please use unset() function

```
$array = array {
  ["De"]=>
  string(7) "treatee"
  ["Para"]=>
  string(13) "Cristina Isabel Gnap"
  ["Principio"]=>
  string(36) "Agilidade, como dinÃ¢mica de aÃ§Ã£o."
  ["Descricao"]=>
  string(8) "sadsadsa"
}

unset($array['pra']);
```